# Redux selector pattern and performance

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've come across this link that briefly describes the advantages of the Redux selector pattern:

https://gist.github.com/abhiaiyer91/aaf6e325cf7fc5fd5ebc70192a1fa170

They provide an example of calling the filtering inside mapStateToProps:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    incompleteItems: getIncompleteItems(state)
  }
}
```

However, since mapStateToProps is called whenever a state changes, even if the change is completely unrelated to the items list, isn't there a performance penalty in this case? wouldn't it be best to do the filtering inside the reducer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The above code snippet just mentions that you should extract the "calculations" from your mapStateToProps function to another function.

The other function could be easily testable and the best part for what you mentioned of not recalculating on each cycle.

`Now we can reuse this logic across many components mapping this exact state! We can unit test it as well! More importantly we can now memoize this state with reselect`

in this case, you can use `reselect` package

https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

and that will take care of recalculating or n

Answer (score 0):

There would indeed be a wasted re-render if you've bound to a prop which didn't actually change, but your other props did. There are 2 things you can do in this case -

1. **Use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)** -
   You can go ahead and implement a shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method for your component. Simply checking for the change for the prop and returning false, will give you immediate results.
2. **Use Immutable data structures** - 
   You can ( and should in my opinion ) use immutable date structures for your application. This not only allows you to help better reason about your app, but also with debugging. Using immutable data structure for your local states will allow for advanced memoization patterns and optimizations.
   Check out [immutable-js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) by facebook for more details.
3. **State modelling** - This is not really a thing we developer think a lot about while coding our super cool apps, but this a worth thing to consider while think in the direction of perf. Keeping re-renders local to the actual data changes is a painful task, and tools such as reselect, immutablejs and side-effect management libs such as redux-saga and redux-thunk, help a lot.

Hope this turns out to be useful for you! Cheer!